# Javascript function to hide HTML textbox on PageLoad

Tags: c#, javascript, html

So I have a search textbox at the top of my website in the Master Page that I wish to disappear when the user is transferred to my search page. My textbox is written like so:

```
  <div class = "SearchBox">
    <form action="javascript:searchSite()">
      <input type="text" id="searchIn" />
    </form>
  </div>
```

The best way I could think to do this was to have some JavaScript run on the PageLoad event of my search page, like so:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "show", "<script>document.getElementById('searchIn').style.display = 'none'</script>");
        }
   }
```

I am fairly certain that the javascript works, because sometimes the textbox will disappear for a second or two. Regardless, it immediately comes back and won't remain hidden.  I have a asp:Textbox that I can easily hide using:

```
  Site1 m = Master as Site1;
        m.OtherTextBox.Visible = false;
```

I don't understand why hiding the HTML textbox is so difficult. Any suggestions or thoughts on how to remedy this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you try `visiblity:hidden`?

Comment: Yes, it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Page_Load` is a server-side event, but you have to also wait for the element to be loaded on the client side. You can wrap you js code in a `window.onload` handler:

```
this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "show", "<script>window.onload = function() { document.getElementById('searchIn').style.display = 'none'; }</script>");
```

Also, use `display: none` as explained by SLaks.

Comment: I had to delete some code in my Page-Load, but it works!! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

`display: hidden` is not a valid CSS value.

You want `display: none`.